# How to suppress violations in PMD?

Tags: java, spring, pmd

When I run a PMD analysis I receive violation:

> Each class should declare at least one constructor

This violation is on a Spring controller. This controller is instantiated by Spring, so I shouldn't need to invoke this class.

What is recommended way of ignoring this violation?

According to [this doc](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3/suppressing.html) can use `//NOPMD` but I just want to ignore specific violation.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

PMD also supports the @SuppressWarnings annotations:

```
// This will suppress all the PMD warnings in this class
@SuppressWarnings("PMD")
public class Bar {
 void bar() {
  int foo;
 }
}
```

Or just one type of warning:

```
// This will suppress UnusedLocalVariable warnings in this class
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedLocalVariable")
public class Bar {
 void bar() {
  int foo;
 }
}
```

And what you might also want to look into are [creating rulesets](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html) and [suppressing warnings](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html). Maybe you want to disable a certain rule, or exclude certain files and folders from PMD checking.

Comment: There's also the [official documentation](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html) from PMD about suppressions: 

If you want to ignore multiple warnings:
`@SuppressWarnings({"PMD.UnusedLocalVariable", "PMD.UnusedPrivateMethod"})`

Comment: Outdated answer. As of PMD 7.0.0-rc4 (https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html), It is @SuppressWarnings('PMD.UnusedLocalVariable, PMD.UnusedPrivateMethod')

Comment: @compski the answer is still relevant. Yours only apply when using Apex

Answer (score 1):

In my organization I use the PMD ignore option in POM file to suppress all warnings that are generated for client stubs (and kept in separate module) that we auto-generate, as those are third party client-stubs we don't tend to touch them thought there are any warnings or violations and I am assuming the same thing for you as we well.

Below is a snippet from POM file, which has client stub module

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> -->
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>       
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

This way we can entirely skip the warnings that are raised by PMD plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore a rule for the entire project you can create a custom ruleset:

**config/pmd/pmd-ruleset.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ruleset name="custom rules">
    <rule ref="category/java/errorprone.xml">
        <exclude name="AvoidLiteralsInIfCondition" />
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Inside my `build.gradle` file (I use Gradle for dependency management) I then add:

```
pmd {
    incrementalAnalysis = true
    ruleSetFiles = files("${rootDir}/config/pmd/pmd-ruleset.xml")
    ruleSets = []
}
```

#### Links

[Making rulesets | PMD](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html)

[Suppressing warnings | PMD](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html)